# How to modify a scope in Sync Framework?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am new to using sync framework and need help in fixing an issue.

The system we built is a window based application. Each user will have their own database in their local. End of the day they sync their database to the remote DB server when they are within the network.

I added two new columns to an existing table. Scope definition seems to be updated in my local database. But when I try to do a sync with my remote DB server it says could not find _bulk-insert store procedure and errors out.

When checked in my remote DB server. I could see the new columns in the table and I don't see any of the store procedures. Scope-config table does not have the new columns in it.

Do the remote server needs to have the store procedure or updating the scope config table will do?

Answer (score 1):

have you provisioned your remote DB server? if you're not finding the sync fx related objects then its not provisioned.

likewise, Sync Fx do not support schema synchronisation. there's nothing on the API to allow you to alter the scope definition either.

it's either you drop and re-create the scope and re-sync, or you hack your way into the Sync Fx scope definition metadata.